# issue while fetch data from sqlite table

Tags: ios, swift, database, sqlite

i am creating app with works when user is online or offline so for that i used `sqlite` database so when i am retrieving data from table i am not able to retrieve data here is my code for fetching data

```
func get_sub_element_offline_data(){
    self.subelementOfflineData.removeAll()
    let fileURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
                .appendingPathComponent("EOBA.sqlite")

    if sqlite3_open(fileURL.path, &db) != SQLITE_OK {
        print("error opening database")
    }
    let queryString = "SELECT * FROM Sub_ElementList_NEW1 WHERE element_id = \(elementID)"
    var stmt:OpaquePointer?

    if sqlite3_prepare(db, queryString, -1, &stmt, nil) != SQLITE_OK{
        let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
        print("error preparing insert: \(errmsg)")
        return
    }
    while(sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW){  //here while statement not able to execute
        let id = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0)
        let element_id = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1))
        let sub_elements_id = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 2))
        let fk_elements_id = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 3))
        let title = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 4))
        print(id)
        print(element_id)
        print(sub_elements_id)
        print(fk_elements_id)
        print(title)
        subelementOfflineData.append(SubElementOfflineModel(id: Int(id), sub_elements_id: String(describing: sub_elements_id), title: String(describing: title)))
        do {
            let jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(subelementOfflineData)
            let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!
            print(jsonString)
        } catch {
            print(error)

        }
    }
}
```

i am fetching data based on element list i have check element id exists in same table but still i am not able to fetch data

so please help on this

Comment: "Not able to...", like how? Do you get an error, have you tried to debug etc?

Comment: no i don't get any error but while statement doesn't execute

Comment: So no rows returned then by the query, have you checked that `elementID` id correctly set (maybe print queryString)?

Comment: yes i have checked element id correctly set but still i am not able tor return row even query executed successfully but row is not returned

Comment: Well if everything is performing correctly and no rows are returned then there are no rows in the database table for that id and not very much we can do to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I worked on a library called [SundeedQLite](https://github.com/noursandid/SundeedQLite), it will help you do all of these, check it out and reply back with any comment